# What's a good strategy for defeating the Cyberdemon?

Tags: doomrl

I've played all the way through *Doom, the Roguelike* to the Cyberdemon several times now, but on every build I've tried, he simply outguns me.

What is a good way to prepare for the Cyberdemon fight?

Comment: Pro Tip: Shoot it until it dies

Comment: I bet you gave the same advice to the Cyberdemon. :-) @BenBrocka

Comment: I find it applies to most things really.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How funny the previous answer may be, surprisingly it holds -- DoomRL has its own reimplementation of strafing - the dodge mechanics. Basically, if when the enemy fires, your last action was a move not directly towards or backwards from the enemy, there is a chance that the enemy will fire at the position you WERE instead of where you ARE. Basically it's sidestepping. The chance is increased by:

- hellrunner trait
- movement speed (light armor and A-modded boots help)
- a lot by running mode (but it decreses aiming!)
- dodgemaster **guarantees** the first dodge will be successful

So basically it's a good idea to stock-up on dodge chance, and fire when Cybie is reloading, sidestep when you think he will fire.

Using this strategy, if you have Dodgemaster and enough ammo, you can actually kill Cybie with a pistol without being even scratched (there's a medal for that too ^_^)

Comment: Awesome to hear they implemented sidetrafing in doomRL

Comment: Yeah, they're great xP

Comment: @Ben, actually, Kornel is the game author :D

Answer (score 1):

To help you survive a bit longer if you don't have Dodgemaster...

Cybie's rockets do fire damage. So, increase your fire resistance:

- wear a red armor
- desirably power-modded
- there are armors with even better fire resistances. If you find/make them, save them for Cybie.
- be in berserk
- use an enviro-suit

Invulnerability is pretty obvious, if you're lucky to have the sphere near the exit from Deimos 7. A pity, it doesn't last long enough to run up to Cybie and kill it.

Technicians use medkits in 0.1s, so it's safe for them to use them anytime. Others need to take cover, in order not to get hit while bandaging.